# Error in VS2017 - LNK2019 unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio, lnk2019

I have following C/C++ project in VS2017:

- **MySolution**

  - **MyProject**

    - AClass.h,AClass.cpp

      - protected foo(){...};
    - BClass.h,BClass.cpp
    - .....
    - **x64\Debug**

      - AClass.obj
      - BClass.obj
      - MyProject.lib
      - MyProject.dll
  - **MyProjectTest**

    - AClassTest.cpp

This is project setting:

- **MyProjectTest** setting :

  - Add reference to MyProject
  - Configuration Properties

    1. C/C++ -> Addtional Include Diretories : ..\MyProjectTest;..\MyProjectTest\x64\Debug
    2. Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories -> : ..\MyProjectTest\x64\Debug
    3. Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies -> : **MyProject.lib**

This is how I test protected `foo()` :

```
include "AClass.h"
class AClassTest : AClass {
   public:
   void wrapFoo() {
     return foo(); //Call AClass::foo()
   }
}
```

When I build Solution, I got this error :

```
 AClasstest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl AClass::~AClass(void)" (??1AClass@@QEAA@XZ) 
    referenced in function "public: __cdecl AClassTest::~AClassTest(void)" (??AClassTest@@QEAA@XZ)

 AClasstest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl AClass::foo(void)" (??1AClass@@QEAA@XZ) 
referenced in function "public: __cdecl AClassTest::wrapFoo(void)" (??foo@AClassTest@@QEAA@XZ)
```

I known that so many question about this problem. I was try with some accepted answer but still no luck

Are there any missing setting in MyProjectTest?

Comment: You don't show the code for `AClass`, but it appears you've told the compiler that you'll define the destructor for `AClass` but don't define it anyplace (or don't link with the source module that contains the definition).

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm AClass.cpp was already defined destructor and `foo()` method. But by some way it's could not recognized in from `AClassTest`